# GUI in Amazon EC2 Linux instance

Tags: user-interface, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to use Amazon EC2 but I need to know if an AMI with Linux distribution with GUI exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works on RHEL 6.3 64-bit: (note: `#` means superuser and can be replaced by `sudo`)

```
# yum groupinstall "Desktop"    
# yum install tigervnc-server xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
# vncserver 
# chkconfig vncserver on

# vi /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```

Edit the last two lines, **uncommenting** them, where myuser is a created user (usually ec2-user).

```
VNCSERVERS="2:myuser"  
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1280x1024"
```

Save changes.

Edit iptables:

```
# vi /etc/iptables
```

Add this line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
```

Restart iptables:

```
# service iptables restart
```

Next, edit the xstartup file:

```
# vi /root/.vnc/xstartup
```

Make the last line be:

```
exec  gnome-session
```

To finish:

- Reboot the instance (to reset your vncserver services)
- Ensure the amazon security group allows tcp 5902 traffic
- Launch a VNC Viewer such as RealVNC's on your local computer
- Connect to public_ip:5902

Comment: `yum groupinstall "Desktop"` gives me Warning: Group basic-desktop does not have any packages to install.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update. Any ideas?

Comment: That works like a charm even tho I also get the error mentioned above this comment.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it exits. But you can usually install a VNC server on any Linux installation, including existing AMIs. And then connect using a VNC client to get remote desktop.

Or use an NX server and client.

Or even plain X protocol, but this will be very slow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My knowledge of linux's command line is very limited. I have found a solution, instead of start a linux AMI I have run Windows OS AMI.

Comment: This Windows stuff... I don't know; you'll pay more for those AMIs, they're attacked by viruses more often, and a bit overly complex (ergo less efficient performance wise) for most uses.  If you have a specific task, avoid it, I always say.

Answer (score 2):

You can install GNOME on LINUX AMI's for GUI. You can also make use of NOMACHINE for this.
If you are making use of Ubuntu AMI's follow steps mentioned below :

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the post [here](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_12.shtml) if you are interested in using Freenx to connect to an Amazon AMI using Fedora, CentOS, RHEL (or any other yum based distro).

Comment: The link is dead. If you have an updated link for your post, please add it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions (thanks to Renan from AWS) I received May 2015.

1. Launch a new, or use an existing, Ubuntu instance. I used Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, 64-bit.10:08:04 AM
2. Update the system package list:10:08:04 AM
   sudo apt-get update10:08:04 AM
3. Optional - I recommend upgrading all installed packages, even the kernel. There may be reasons not to want this, however:10:08:04 AM
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade10:08:04 AM
4. Install LXDE and TightVNC (This will take a while, depending on the instance type):10:08:04 AM
   sudo apt-get install lxde tightvncserver10:08:04 AM
5. Reboot the system:10:08:04 AM
   sudo reboot10:08:04 AM
6. Start up a VNC server (on localhost - since VNC itself isn't very secure, we'll use SSH)10:08:04 AM
   vncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -localhost :110:08:04 AM
   Note: the VNC server will ask you to set and confirm a password. You will use this when you connect your VNC client.10:08:04 AM
7. Install a suitable VNC viewer, such as TightVNC on Windows: http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php 10:08:04 AM
   or Remmina on Linux (usually installed by default, or at least available in the repositories).10:08:04 AM
   Sorry, I'm not sure what Mac users install for VNC, but apparently there's a Java-based viewer at least: http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php#macosx 10:08:04 AM
8. Create an SSH tunnel:10:08:04 AM
   ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -N -f -i  ubuntu@10:08:04 AM
   On Windows PuTTY, enter the usual settings (login, address, key file) then go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels and enter 5901 for Source Port and localhost:5901 for Destination, then click Add, and start your session.10:08:04 AM
9. Finally, launch your VNC viewer and connect to localhost:5901, then enter the VNC password you chose earlier.10:08:04 AM
10. Enjoy your encrypted, remote Linux GUI.